# ProjectOxford SpeechRecognition

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I'm creating a bot using bot framework. I tested it on Skype channel and it works at last Skype is talking to me not other way ( Skype is not answering to my speech) 
I tried : 
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-STT-Windows which give me the following error when i press on record : : 'A procedure imported by 'SpeechClient.dll' could not be loaded.'

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/skype-CallingBot/IVRBot.cs This one is not listening to my commands, he is asking me to press 1 (speech ?) i tried dial/text/speech not working. It is stuck in a infinite loop with this message : ""If you have a life threatening medical emergency please contact the emergency services or go to your nearest hospital. For non-life threatening situations please press 1."

https://ankitbko.github.io/2016/11/skype-call-your-bot/ 
I also tried this one. While i install project Oxford for Speech Recognition and i run my application nothing is working anymore. The other end doesn't get my inputs also if i try to call skype it tells me that is configured wrong. As soon as i take out this library everything is working correctly again.

What alternative of speech recognition could i use here instead of oxford -- which i read that have some windows 8 dependencies and i'm running it on windows 7.

```
private async Task OnRecordCompleted(RecordOutcomeEvent recordOutcomeEvent)
    {
        if (recordOutcomeEvent.RecordOutcome.Outcome == Outcome.Success)
        {
            var record = await recordOutcomeEvent.RecordedContent;

            //---- here record should become text ----

            recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
            {
                GetSilencePrompt()
            };
        }
        else
        {
            if (silenceTimes > 1)
            {
                recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetPromptForText("Thank you for calling"),
                    new Hangup() { OperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
                };
                recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Links = null;
                silenceTimes = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                silenceTimes++;
                recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetRecordForText("I didn't catch that, would you kinly repeat?")
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

---edit

[image]

Also this is the error that i get after trying to deploy it on azure with "Microsoft.CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognition" (ProjectOxford) at my references. Now i cannot get rid of it even if i try to publish without this reference installed (maybe it give some clue about what is happening)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency problem. Oxford doesn't run on windows 7!